# How to find the output of the transformation when the basis is entirely different?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question about transformations. I feel I have a lot of pieces but just can't put the puzzle together.

I am aware that the basis $B$ creates the coordinates on which the matrix receives input and spits out as a transformed image. Using this logic, I found that $e_1$ $<1,0,0>$ can be expressed as a linear combination of the basis vectors in $B$ $(-1\cdot v_1 + 2 \cdot v_2 + 2\cdot v_3)$ but I am now stuck after this part. Any help appreciated!

Here are details:

### Linear Map Value via Matrix (non-standard basis)

Let $T:V\rightarrow V$ be linear map where $V=R^3$. Assume that the matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis $B$ is
$\begin{pmatrix}
5 &0 &0\\
1 &5 &0 \\
0 &1 &5
\end{pmatrix}$, where $B = \left[\begin{pmatrix}1\\-2\\0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0\\-1\\1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\-1\end{pmatrix}\right]$.

Find $T(\mathbf{e_1})$, where
$$\mathbf{e_1}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Maybe you can rewrite the question using MathJax? https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Welcome. Posting image is discouraged. [Images](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13677/963109) may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. Since you are new contributor, the images have been converted to text for once (If you can't see text, assume that conversion process is in Queue). It is advisable to get yourself trained with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/963109) so that from future you can type your question self. Happy Learning!

Answer (score 2):

Write (1, 0, 0) in terms of those basis vectors!
That is, find a, b, c so that
(1, 0, 0)= a(1, -2, 0)+ b(0, -1, 1)+ c(1, 0, -1).

writing the three dimensions separately
a+ c= 1, -2a- b= 0, and b- c= 0.

From the last equation c= b.  So now we have a+ b= 1 and -2a- b= 0.
Adding those equations eliminates b and gives -a= 1 so a= -1.  Then a+ b= -1+ b= -1+ c= 1 so b= c= 2.

In terms of this basis, (1, 0, 0) is (-1, 1, 1).

You need to calculate $\begin{pmatrix}5 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 5 & 0 \\0 & 1 & 5\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$